# Disappearing Conky

Tags: unity, 14.10, conky

Every time I launch my conky, and I click anywhere on the desktop, it disappears, and I have to keep relaunching it, does anyone have a solution?

Comment: post your config

Answer (score 5):

Open your conkyrc file with

```
nano .conkyrc
```

and then

made the changes for the following lines

```
own_window yes
own_window_class Conky
own_window_type normal 
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager  
own_window_transparent yes
```

Then kill your conky and try again launching.

let us know if any issues.

[credit goes here](http://lwathcrunch.blogspot.in/2014/12/fix-conky-hiding.html)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I've found out too to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

{own_window_type panel}

also seems to work, but omits the window border et. al. present if you use

{own_window_type normal}

The important thing is that somehow either one does prevent the conky window from being covered by the desktop.

When you do a File Save on .conkyrc then conky will reload without need of a formal kill and restart.

Answer (score 0):

I tried every option for `own_window_type` to get Conky to persist on my desktop, all to no avail. I finally found that setting

```
background=false;
```

in .conkyrc and making sure to not autostart conky with the `-d` flag did the trick once and for all.