# After the upgrade to 15.10 Conky disappears when I click desktop

Tags: 15.10, conky

The conky window disappears if I click the desktop (but not in "super+D" (show desktop).

I have tried all possible setting. My previously working settings in 15.04 is as follows:

```
own_window_type desktop
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorate,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager,below
```

Comment: That disappearing is a bug in nautilus.

Comment: Duplicate here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/582950/disappearing-conky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My working settings on 14.04, on which I used to have the same problem:

```
own_window yes
own_window_type normal
own_window_class conky
own_window_hints undecorated,skip_taskbar,skip_pager,sticky,below
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_transparent yes
```

I think the key is `own_window_type` set to `normal` instead of `desktop`.

Answer (score 1):

I do not use own_window_type but rather set the own_window_hints by hand in a custom configuration.  I do not have any issue with the conky window disappearing.  Feel free to copy as many of my settings as you need to figure out where yours is failing to do the job.

Alternatively if you post your .conkyrc file, we could attempt to debug it for you.

```
alignment                   middle_right                  # Display on right edge of screen, vertically centered
background                  yes                           # Fork to background
cpu_avg_samples             3                             # Sample and average CPU cores three times
default_bar_size            208 10                        # Set bar height
default_color               gold                          # Set default text color to gold
double_buffer               yes                           # Enable double buffering to eliminate flicker
gap_x                       6                             # Offset horizontal placement to allow a one pixel gap between window and screen edge
gap_y                       0                             # Make conky respect the vertical centering
if_up_strictness            link                          # An ethernet connection is only considered to be up if there's an active link
maximum_width               297                           # Set width - 307px
minimum_size                297                           # Set width - 307px
net_avg_samples             3                             # Sample and average network activity three times
no_buffers                  yes                           # Disregard file system buffers when calculating memory usage
own_window                  yes                           # Required to minimize double buffer size
own_window_argb_value       191                           # Set conky background opacity (0 transparent, 63-127-191 25-50-75% translucent, 255 opaque)
own_window_argb_visual      yes                           # Enable ARGB settings
own_window_hints            undecorated                   # No window decorations
own_window_hints            below                         # Always visible as a desktop element under any other windows
own_window_hints            sticky                        # Sticky across workspaces
own_window_hints            skip_taskbar                  # Do not display to taskbar
own_window_hints            skip_pager                    # Do not display to other application switchers
pad_percents                3                             # Stabilize layout
temperature_unit            celsius                       # Show temperatures in Celsius
top_name_width              20                            # Set top name width (Default is 15 characters)
update_interval             0.5                           # Set update speed
use_spacer                  left                          # Stabilize layout
use_xft                     yes                           # Employ XFT anti-aliased fonts
xftfont                     DejaVu Sans Mono:size=9       # Select an appropriate font and size
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I just discovered something that might make this whole Conky-Lubuntu issue go away. Set `background=false` in `.conkyrc` and be sure you're not autostarting Conky with the `-d` flag. I tried every other suggestion I could find, and sometimes they would work and sometimes not, and even if they worked it was only for a little while. Keeping Conky in the foreground seems to do the trick. Hope this helps somebody.